# Header spacing to the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get spacing before and after my background colour to my header. I can get the left side spacing by using:

```
header {
    background-color: #888888;
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
    top: 3px;
}
```

But, when I want to add spacing to the right by adding `right: 60px`, It just ignores it and the colour reaches the right of the page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change position: relative to position: absolute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's about using [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) instead of `position: relative` + `top`/`right`/`left`?

```css
header {
    background-color: #888888;
    margin: 3px 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/fLxvgngq/)

About `left`/`right` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right):

> When both the `right` CSS property and the `left` CSS property are defined, the position of the element is *overspecified*. In that case, the `left` value has precedence when the container is left-to-right (that is that the `right` computed value is set to `-left`), and the `right` value has precedence when the container is right-to-left (that is that the `left` computed value is set to `-right`).

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm! Just for future reference, what is the "0" for? after 60px?

Comment: @Zettsyuk I'm glad to help. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), when we use 3 values, 3rd value is `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Thanks! this'll definitely help down the road.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set:

```
header{
    background-color: #888888;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100vw - 120px);
    margin: 3px 60px 0 60px;
}
```

`width: calc(100vw - 120px);` is calculated width that equal 100% of viewport width minus 120px. after that you just need to set equal margins (60px) on the left and right sides

Answer (score 0):

You seems to misunderstand the function of `left` or `right`. It does not just give you left or right space but **moves / positions the entire element(header)** to the left or right. It goes in hand with the property `position: relative`.

In your case you are just positioning the header to right first by 60px and then positioning it back towards left by 60px which brings it back exactly to the same position, hence no gap seen. This is not the right approach.

Instead just use `margin` to give you the space required like so:

```
header{
    ... left, right not needed ...

    margin: 0 60px 0 60px;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps!